# How to do content level search in AmazonS3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some files(.txt, .doc, .xlsx etc) inside a bucket in my AmazonS3 drive and is it possible to perform a content level search through my C# application? That is, when we type a string and upon pressing  key in my application, every files that contains the searched string in its content should list.

Is there any way to achieve this either using any method or even using WebAPI's.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not possible to do without downloading and parsing through every file. S3 doesn't support content search. You should be indexing these files in a search engine like Elasticsearch in addition to storing them in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is purely a storage service. There is **no search capability** built into S3.

You could use services such as [Amazon CloudSearch](http://gregfrewintheatre.com/hire-greg-frewin.html) and [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/), which can index documents, but please note that this involves additional configuration and additional costs.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do all those file types you listed, but any of your files that are structured, or semi-structured, you could consider using the newly released **AWS Athena** which does allow searching of S3 file using an SQL-like language:

https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/

> Amazon Athena is an interactive query service that makes it easy to
>   analyze data in Amazon S3 using standard SQL. Athena is serverless, so
>   there is no infrastructure to setup or manage, and you can start
>   analyzing data immediately. You don’t even need to load your data into
>   Athena, it works directly with data stored in S3. To get started, just
>   log into the Athena Management Console, define your schema, and start
>   querying. Amazon Athena uses Presto with full standard SQL support and
>   works with a variety of standard data formats, including CSV, JSON,
>   ORC, Apache Parquet and Avro. While Amazon Athena is ideal for quick,
>   ad-hoc querying and integrates with Amazon QuickSight for easy
>   visualization, it can also handle complex analysis, including large
>   joins, window functions, and arrays.

Comment: Thanks Brennan.
Is it possible to use Athena with my third party C# application? If so will it cost extra? Also if it is possible, how  can integrate with my application. Can you please provide some sample code?